# How to get ssl certificates from letsencrypt for windows server Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, lets-encrypt, windows-server-2016

I am struggling for ssl(letsencrypt) for last 2 days ,i don't know how to get these certificates.
My server is running on tomcat 8,where i need to use ssl for my application.
From my side i had tried certbot(nginx) where failed to create verification folder,
and acmesharp but failed.
Please guide me steps to generate certificates for my domain.I am mentioning again windows server with tomcat 8

Comment: @gongqin Can you help me over this , i took your refrence from your question